# How to solve Discord high cpu usage on a Macbook pro when sharing a screen

Tags: discord

On my Macbook Pro with the latest OS intel chip, when I use the Discord screen sharing feature, the CPU gets at 90%, and all becomes very laggy at this level  I cannot use my Mac.

I tried to follow the guides online but cannot resolve this issue, and my work is giving me problems.

there are other solutions which I may be not aware of it